# Interfacing Pic18 with mmc/sd

Tags: sd-card, pic, pic18

I want to communicate an Pic18 with an MMC to build a dataLogger. I already tried to use the mmc_spi.c standard library to send a simple sentence to the MMC but I can´t even initialize it without error. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <18f25k20.h>
#fuses HS, NOWDT, PUT, NOLVP
#use delay(clock=4M)

#use rs232(baud=9600, xmit=PIN_C6, rcv=PIN_C7)

#define MMC_CLK   PIN_C3
#define MMC_DI    PIN_C4
#define MMC_DO    PIN_C5
#define MMC_CS    PIN_C2
#include <mmc_spi.c>

void main() 
{

printf("\n\rTest MMC_SPI\n\r"); 

if(mmc_init()==0) 
   printf("\n\rSuccessfully initialized\n\r"); 
else 
   printf("\n\rError\n\r"); 
}
```

I also enabled a print out debbug message and I get:

```
ERR: MMC is busy
ERR: after reset, device ins´t idle
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your hardware connection between PIC18 and SDcard? 
Interface with a SDcard through SPI is usually simple, I think you have an issue in your circuit.